# Schedule a python script on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, scheduler

I deployed my python script on Heroku and trying to setup scheduler to run it every hour.

My Procfile:

```
run: cd src && python3 main.py
```

I scale this dyno with:

```
heroku ps:scale run=1
```

And in heroku scheduler I set it for run every hour with command

```
run
```

Deploy and I think that it will runs every hour, but it runs more often than I expect, every 10-15 minutes, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scale your "run" process type down to 0 with `heroku ps:scale run=0`.
Thern, make sure you can run it in a [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos), e.g. with `heroku run python src/main.py`.

Then in Heroku Scheduler configure the exact same command that you used to run it in a one-off dyno, and configure your required frequency (i.e. "Hourly").